# doubled labels in barplot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, label

I work on a dataset with flights delays. 
The dataset is available on : 
https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time

The fact is that when I want to plot a barplot of the aggregation of my delays by day of month, my labels are doubled on the x axis.

[My barplot picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf4iX.png)

How can you explain that ? 
I already verified that my "DAY_OF_MONTH" values were unique with :

```
np.unique(list(df['DAY_OF_MONTH']))
```

The code is :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
grouped = df[['ARR_DELAY', 'DAY_OF_MONTH']].groupby('DAY_OF_MONTH').mean()
grouped.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,10))
plt.title('Retard moyen des départs de vols selon les jours du mois, en minutes')
```

Comment: One set of  values in DAY_OF_MONTH is probably integers and the other set is  a set strings. See the string numeric sorting of the last part of your graph (1 followed by 10 and not 2)? Compare that to the sorting in the beginning of the graph where all numeric values are in the order you expect. To prevent that double sorting simply make sure the dtype of DAY_OF_MONTH is integer for all rows.

Comment: Ok super ! I did'nt excpected that I could have more than 1 datatype in a same column. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is typecasting to numpy array. Your input data while reading read few value as numeric and few as character. When you are checking the unique values using numpy, it first converts your pandas series to a numpy array and forces all the elements to become a String, and then count unique, which results in right count, but while plotting typecasting doesn't happen.

You need to explicitly do the casting (see example below) -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 12, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 12],
                  'Col2' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,6,7,9,1,3,6,1,8,5,]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',' 12',' 1','2','3','4',\
                             '5','6','7','8','9','10','11',' 12'],
                  'Col2' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,6,7,9,1,3,6,1,8,5,]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
print(np.unique(list(df['Col1'])))


df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype('int32')
print(np.unique(list(df['Col1'])))
```

> [' 1' ' 12' '1' '10' '11' '12' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9']
>
> [ 1  23  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]